# Area 51 Proposal pages need explanation of 'Commit' and 'Follow'

Tags: feature-request, area-51, commitment

An explanation of what 'Commit' and 'Follow' mean needs to be easier to find from the Area 51 Proposal pages.

Perhaps something like this that links to the FAQ page:
[image]

or even just add a tooltip on this button that says 'Commit.  Learn about committing on the FAQ page'.
[image]

Why not make it as easy as possible for new users to find the info they need?

Comment: I think it's decently explained between "[the site] needs people to commit to use it" and the message on the commit pop-up...but the second one requires them clicking the button. Do you feel as though that information doesn't explain things well enough, or do you think that people will be hesitant to click the button without understanding what commitment is first?

Comment: @Tim: You nailed it - 'people will be hesitant to click the button without understanding what commitment is first'.  I definitely think the commit button seems a bit ominous (when in fact it's not at all).  Either the explanation in the pop up needs to be more easily found (without clicking the scarey commit button).  Or change the commit button text to 'Learn about committing' or something along those lines.